# Menú dinámico con PHP, MySQL y JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html5, codeigniter

Estoy haciendo un menú dinámico con `PHP`, `MySQL` y `Javascript`.

Quiero hacer algo similar a los menús de esta `template` https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign , en esta pagina cuando paso de pagina en pagina los menus quedan seleccionados y abiertos pero al hacerlo dinámico no me agrega las clases que son necesarias para que quede seleccionado y abierto el menú.

Código:

```html
<!--Aqui esta el aside donde se inserta el menú-->
    <!-- #Top Bar -->
    <section>
        <!-- Left Sidebar -->
        <aside id="leftsidebar" class="sidebar">
            <!-- User Info -->
            <div class="user-info">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/template/images/user.png" width="48" height="48" alt="User" />
                </div>
                <div class="info-container">
                    <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $this->session->userdata("nomUsuario"); ?>  <?php echo $this->session->userdata("apeUsuario"); ?></div>
                    <div class="email"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('correo'); ?></div>
                    <div class="btn-group user-helper-dropdown">
                        <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Profile</a></li>
                            <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">group</i>Followers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i>Likes</a></li>
                            <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>auth/logout"><i class="material-icons">input</i>Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #User Info -->
            <!-- Menu -->
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="header">MENU DE NAVEGACION</li>
                    <!--Aqui estoy insertando el menú -->
                    <?php echo $this->backend_lib->getMenu(); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- #Menu -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <div class="legal">
                <div class="copyright">
                   &copy; 2018 <a href="#">Dive Web System</a> Todos los derechos reservados.
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #Footer -->
        </aside>
        <!-- #END# Left Sidebar -->
    </section>
    
 -------------------------------------





public function getMenu()
    {
        $menu    = '';
        $parents = $this->CI->Backend_model->getParents($this->CI->session->userdata("idRol"));
        foreach ($parents as $parent) {
            $children   = $this->CI->Backend_model->getChildren($this->CI->session->userdata("idRol"), $parent->idpagina);
            $linkParent = $parent->link == '#' ? '#' : base_url($parent->link);
            if (!$children) {
                $identi = $parent->identificador;
                if ($identi == 1) {
                    $menu .= '
                    <li class="active" id="' . $parent->identificador . '">
                        <a id="' . $parent->identificador . '"  href="' . $parent->link . '"  class="toggled waves-effect waves-block">
                            <i class="material-icons">' . $parent->icono . '</i>
                            <span>' . $parent->pagina . '</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>';
                }
                if ($identi != 1) {
                    $menu .= '
                    <li id="' . $parent->identificador . '">
                        <a id="' . $parent->identificador . '" href="' . $parent->link . '" class="waves-effect waves-block">
                            <i class="material-icons">' . $parent->icono . '</i>
                            <span>' . $parent->pagina . '</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>';
                }

            } else {
                $menu .= '
                    <li id="' . $parent->identificador . '">
                        <a class="menu-toggle waves-effect waves-block">
                            <i class="material-icons">' . $parent->icono . '</i>
                            <span>' . $parent->pagina . '</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="ml-menu" id="' . $parent->identificador . '">';
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $identi2 = $child->identificador;
                    $url2    = $child->link;
                    $menu .= '
                        <li id="' . $child->identificador . '">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-block" id="' . $child->identificador . '" href="' . $url2 . '">' . $child->pagina . '</a>
                        </li>';
                }
                $menu .= '</ul></li>';
            }
        }
        return $menu;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la Clase `active` para que se muestre Activa la sección en la que estas?

Comment: Hola Eduardo si la clase **active** y que se mantenga abierta el menú

Comment: No es complicado, ¿Estas utilizando Codeigniter?

Comment: Asi es estoy utilizando codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

En `Codeigniter` puedes hacer uso de `$this->uri->segment(n);` que te permite recuperar un segmento específico. Donde `n` es el número de segmento que desea recuperar. Los segmentos se numeran de izquierda a derecha.

Por ejemplo:

```
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
```

Los números de segmento serían estos:

1. news
2. local
3. metro
4. crime_is_up

Entonces, para poder crear tu menú con la clase `active` si tu `URL` es simple puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>person/profile" <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="name_menu"){echo 'class="active"';}?> ><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>View Profile</a>
</li>
```

Le estas diciendo que si la `URL` en su segmento `n` es igual al nombre que tu le asignes en `name_menu` entonces le agregara la clase `active` y con esto podrás ver el menú activo.

Referencia URI: [URI Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)